# WordPress admin panel catching theme CSS rather than admin core CSS

Tags: wordpress, admin, panel

I have installed the `wp 4.7.2` and added an HTML theme. I converted it to Wordpress. But `wp-admin` panel catching theme `style.css` rather than its own core CSS.

Comment: Have you added styles and scripts as per the wordpress standards?

Comment: Yes, I have entered using wp_enqueue_style & wp_enqueue_script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to verify the scripts only include inside the frontend , not inside the wp-admin

You can use `is_admin()`

[Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) is the doc

Comment: Oh Yes, its worked. Thank You. I was trying since last night. Thank You once again.

Comment: If you find the answer helpful than you can mark it as true on the left side. :)